Mile High Club & murderer on a plane
I'm looking for the following movie.
A couple attempt to join the mile high club whilst a murderer slits the throats of some of the passengers on a plane. Before the killings, a woman suffering from nervous flying is seated next to a 'plane crash expert' creep who makes her flight uneasy and uncomfortable. He discusses a particular crash where a flying monster thing was seen on the wing of the plane (followed by cringe worthy impression of said beast).

Welcome to Movies & TV. For the uninitiated you might want to elaborate what you mean with "mile high club". And are there any other details that might help identification? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Any other story details? Feel free to add any additional information you might remember into the question.

You're describing the opening scene of Urban Legends: Final Cut from 2000: A girl panics in a plane full of college students and the guy who sits next to her tries to calm her down with a hammy impression of the gremlin in the Twilight Zone's Nightmare at 20,000 Feet. A couple then head to the bathroom to join the Mile High Club and the girl sees the words "you're going down" on the mirror. When they come out, they discover that all the passengers were slashed to death by a male flight attendant. The whole thing then turns out to be a student film. Here's the trailer:



